# Python "bitwise or" on array

Tags: python, django

I have an array of Django querysets. Django querysets can be merged using the `bitwise or` operator like this:

```
n1 = <queryset ...>
n2 = <queryset ...>
merged = n1 | n2
```

What if I have an array of unspecified size `array = [n1, n2, ...]` and I'd like to do `merged = n1 | n2 | ...`?

```
merged = array[0]
for i in array:
    if (i in array):
        merged = merged | array[i]
```

Is there a more elegant solution? Something like `array.join(|)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `operator` library to get the operator as a function, and you can use `functools.reduce` to operate a bunch of items together.

```
import operator
import functools
merged = functools.reduce(operator.or_, array)
```

The docs of `reduce` are nice and concise:

> Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value. For example, `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` calculates `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`.

In your case, you have `|` instead of `+`, so if you passed it this list, it would calculate `((((1|2)|3)|4)|5)`. This works the same regardless if the list you pass in has numbers or arbitrary objects. You can also use a `lambda` to define your function, but `operator.or_` is more clear.